# Mouse click no more responsive

Tags: gnome, mouse, touchpad, trackpad

I am happily using Ubuntu since the 11.04 release on a Dell Latitude E5530. Unfortunately since I bought this laptop I am encountering some troubles with the mouse (I guess related to the X server) and these problems are more and more frequent with the last 13.04 release.

My configuration is the following one:

- Ubuntu 13.04
- USB mouse (Microsoft) plugged in
- Gnome Shell
- Touchpad gnome shell extension, to disable the track pad when the mouse is plugged

Sometimes (once, twice, more, a day) my mouse clicks are no more available almost every where. I can just click for windows selection in gnome shell, but once in an application, clicks are no more available.

Unplugging the mouse let me use the trackpad again, but the same problem is still there: I can't click with the trackpad. Plugin the mouse into another USB port doesn't change anything.

The only solution is to restart the X server, which not always acceptable.

Are any other Ubuntu users encountering the same issue ? Where does this can come from, and how can I solve it ?

Many thanks for any inputs, advises!

Comment: Did you experience the same problem with touchpad or another USB mouse?

Comment: @RaduRădeanu I didn't try that yet. I'll let you know

Comment: @RaduRădeanu I just experienced the same issue with another mouse in the same USB port. I am now trying on another USB port.

Comment: did you find a solution in the last couple of years?

Comment: @Tomas Unfortunately, no never found any solution.