# Mouse randomly stops clicking

Tags: 16.04, unity, mouse, suspend, dell

This is sort of a weird problem but I'll try and explain it best I can. I am on a Dell Latitude 6430u Ultrabook and I've been running Ubuntu 16.04 for about 10 months without any issues. Last week, my mouse began to not respond to clicks randomly. It started to happen when I put the computer to sleep (by closing the lid) and reopened it, but now it happens intermittently when using my laptop. I've been able to work around this by restarting, but sometimes this requires 3-4 restarts to get the mouse to work.

It seems like the mouse will work in one window that is in focus, but won't be able to switch windows.

I've tried running `unity` in the terminal to restart it but this doesn't solve the issue.

I have a wireless mouse as well, but this has no effect.

Related questions:
(answers don't work for me and some are for older versions)

- [Ubuntu 14.04 mouse and window focus issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451080/ubuntu-14-04-mouse-and-window-focus-issues)
- [Mouse click no more responsive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/303824/mouse-click-no-more-responsive)
- [Mouse clicks stop registering in some or all windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/588646/mouse-clicks-stop-registering-in-some-or-all-windows)

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Not to be funny, but is/are mouse button(s) still ok? Is the battery ok? Is the receiver close enough to the mouse (I had to move the USB receiver to the front of my machine because the metal casing was absorbing the signal).

Comment: Thanks! I believe so. This affects the wireless mouse and the laptop touch pad so I don't think it's that (unless my touchpad mouse buttons died and my wireless mouse battery both are dying at the same time).

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this may not work for everyone but it was driving me crazy and I just couldn't find an answer and especially without being able to use mouse, and only using KB.
Anywho I found that ( for me ) on my kb I had a shortcut to disable mouse/touchpad. Fn + f3. If you have this option and you toggle it, it fixes the problem at least temporarily. It still bugs out on me from time to time but I just toggle it and it works.

-Hope it helps.